# Azure Active Directory B2C and native experience on mobile instead of WebView

Tags: azure, firebase-authentication, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to use Azure Active Directory B2C and have smooth native authorization instead of WebView?

Or it's only available when using additional authentication providers as a middleman (e.g. Firebase Auth)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect with mobile application to AD B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364881/how-to-connect-with-mobile-application-to-ad-b2c)

Answer (score 0):

To be specific, I would like to implement Azure B2C in mobile apps written in Flutter.
When I was investigating Azure auth and how to implement native experience in Flutter:

- I found the dedicated Flutter package that does Azure B2C Auth https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth
- I realized that this dedicated package is opening WebView anyway
- I started the discussion with the author and he confirmed my earlier suspects that without Firebase Auth (or other providers) we won't be able to achieve native authentication

https://github.com/Earlybyte/aad_oauth/issues/100

So 2 solutions come to my mind:

1. Native auth - Firebase Auth (or another provider) communicating with Azure. Something like [Firebase Authentication with Azure AD B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54105594/firebase-authentication-with-azure-ad-b2c)
2. Webview and direct Azure Auth

Am I right or I'm missing something? @Jit_MSFT @Jas Suri - MSFT

Answer (score -1):

Could you manage with Native apps (ios/android) to hold the client secret? If not then register them as native apps, and this way the auth request to get a token does not need a secret.

Here are Samples:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-native-application?tabs=app-reg-ga

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/signin-appauth-ios?tabs=app-reg-ga

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples#mobile-and-desktop-apps

Answer (score -1):

Native app api based authentication, is only supported for Native apps using the ROPC OIDC flow.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Be aware ROPC has certain potential security flaws and is generally not recommended